# Angular components comunication

Tags: angular

i´m trying to create a widget system in my Angular app where each widget is a component and some of them interact with other component.

I have a blogComponent that wraps all my components and calls the post-list component as

```
 <app-post-list
          [author]   = "post_author"
          [category] = "post_categories"
          [search]   = "search_terms"
        ></app-post-list>
```

and my widgets

```
<app-widget-search (WidgetSearchEvent)="WidgetSearchEvent($event)"></app-widget-search>
<app-widget-categories (WidgetCategoriesEvent)="WidgetCategoriesEvent($event)"></app-widget-categories>
<app-widget-text></app-widget-text>
<app-widget-recent-posts></app-widget-recent-posts>
<app-widget-recent-comments></app-widget-recent-comments>
```

So some widget use EvenEmmiter to send a Output value to the app-post-list and it render again the new post list, and It works fine. But now I want to wrap all widgets on other component `side-bar` to get them all as:

```
<app-side-bar></app-side-bar>
```

But if I do this the EventEmiter method dont work. Any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you need to create event emmiters on side bar and go all the way up.
This looks ugly but the only way. Or you can create service between this components, be careful with the visibility of the service if you have many such components depending on your need global or local.
This is the actually the problem that redux solves. When you dont need to go all the way up and wrap emmitters in emmiters. But just dispatch action and it will notify all components.

Comment: thanks for your hint, I saw somenthing about `redux` and `ngrx` but I never use them, and I dont know wich is better, but this is for other question, can you pass me a simple tutorial or something?

Comment: yes. ngrx is implementation of redux pattern but using power of rxjs. you will find a lot of links here https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/store/README.md

Comment: but the main checkout their example app https://github.com/ngrx/platform/tree/master/example-app

Comment: i would say ngrx is redux for angular :-)

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to look into a shared service between the components you want to communicate with, unless you want to have a lot of event emitters for each level. I typically move to sharing data with services beyond direct parent/child communication.